# How do I trigger Command Blocks when a player walks in a certain area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm currently making an adventure map and I want to know how to trigger Command Blocks when a player walks through a certain area. For example, if a player walks through a certain part of a cave, it would say "Don't go down there", or something. Or it could trigger a jump scare (but that's not what I'm looking for).

Specifically, I'm making it so that when the player walks through an area, it says "I think it would be a good idea to go exploring." in a first person perspective.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a first person perspective"?

Answer (score 3):

To test for a player in some distance from a certain place, use:

```
/testfor @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R,rm=RM]
```

Where `X`, `Y` and `Z` are the middle coordinates of the area to test for a player, `R` and `RM` specify the minimum and maximum distances from the specified coordinates, respectively.

To run a command, eg. `/say Hello` when the testfor command returns true, place the @a[] part into an `/execute` command:

```
/execute @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R,rm=RM] ~ ~ ~ /say Hello
```

Comment: I don't think it works, I probably did it wrong because I have no idea what your talking about as I'm not very good at command blocks, I only know simple commands. This is what I did:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   /testfor @a[x=-1,y=111,z=-11,r=4,rm=4] for the first command block and for the second: /execute @a[x=-1,y=111,z=-11,r=4,rm=4] ~ ~ ~ /say Hello

Comment: Or if there was a way to make pressure plates invisible I would do that.

Comment: @RezamatorYT the second value, `rm` is not inclusive - eg. `r=4,rm=4` will never be true, but `r=4,rm=5` should activate if something is in the specified distance. If no player is in the specified area, the command will act as if it was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Spawn an invisible ArmorStand on that place, give it a Name:

1.9.x:

`summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1,CustomName:"sOp"}`

Repeating command block: `execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=sOp] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[r=0] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @s {text:"I think it would be a good idea to go exploring.",color:green,bold:false}`

Answer (score 0):

You could put pressure plates down, then when stood on it could /say (Whatever) then you could use /setblock on whatever coordinates the pressure plate was to replace it with air.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in version 1.14.4 of the Java Edition, on a repeating Command Block.
The command picks every value that's between *x* and *dx* - same with every other axis - and will show whatever message you want:

`/msg @a[x=~,dx=~,y=~,dy=130,z=~,dz=~] (message here)`

Answer (score -1):

I think `/msg @a[x=~,dx=~,y=~,dy=130,z=~,dz=~] (custom message here)` is your best bet.